# Elements from state being erased in react.js even when immutably updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following state in my React main App component:

```
  state = {
    tasks : [],
    tags : [],
    modals : {
      deleteModal : false,
      editmodal   : false,
      addmodal    : false  
    },
    globals : {
      deleteid : null,
      deleteIdx : null,
      edittasktext : null,
      edittaskid : null
    }
  }
```

When i open a modal, the state is edited in the below function , like so ,

```
_handleEditModalOpen = ( id , text ) => {

    let modals = this.state.modals,
    globals = this.state.globals;

    this.setState({
      modals : {
        ...modals,
        editmodal : true
      },
      globals : {
         ...globals,
         edittaskid : id,
         edittasktext : text 
      }
    });

  }
```

As you can see, once of the things I am editing above is the globals, But when i check my state in react debugger, I see that `edittaskid` and `edittasktext` are wiped out, as you can see below, this is how the state looks after the above function runs.

see screenshots below, state when app loads:

[image]

see screenshots below, state when app modal opens and function runs:

[image]

Why are elements from my state being wiped off?

Comment: is `globals` variable declared somewhere or you forgot to put `let`?

Comment: @Vencovsky there is no `globlas` ..

Comment: sorry, little typo

Comment: @Vencovsky its alright :) the `let` used before modals , covers globals as well ..

Comment: **this.state.modal.editmodal** has been true? If so, check the **id** & **text** is the correct data, and then try to console **this.state.globals.edittaskid** & **this.state.globals.edittasktext** in callback like `this.setState({...}, () => {console.log(...)})`